# PyCharm PEP8 Violation for typed parameters

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

PEP8 suggests no spaces around equal operators in function parameters.

For example:

Correct:

```
def func(a=0):
   print('PEP8 compliant spacing')
```

Incorrect:

```
def func(a = 0):
   print('Invalid PEP8 spacing')
```

PyCharm's auto-formatter fails to pick up incorrect spacing when [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) is included.

For example, PyCharm **does not** correctly format the following function:

```
def func(a: int = 0):
    print('Invalid PEP8 spacing')
```

To:

```
def func(a: int=0):
    print('PEP8 compliant spacing')
```

Has anyone found a way to have PyCharm's auto-formatter pick up spacing violations where typing is present?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mistaken in your quoting of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-annotations). The whitespace is supposed to be there in this case:

> When combining an argument annotation with a default value, use spaces around the = sign (but only for those arguments that have both an annotation and a default).
>
> **Yes**:
>
> `def munge(sep: AnyStr = None): ...`
>
> **No**:
>
> `def munge(input: AnyStr=None): ...`
> `def munge(input: AnyStr, limit = 1000): ...`

Comment: Great stuff, thanks for picking that up @FlyingTeller. Don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Although the original post misinterprets the PEP8 standard, there is actually a bug in the formatter with regards to this particular standard, when using a set for the type hint:

```
def foo(a: {str, None}=None):
    print("This is the result before formatting, no PEP8 violation is reported")

def foo(a: {str, None} = None):
        print("This is the result after formatting, the whitespace around the '=' is underlined as a PEP8 violation")
```

The formatting results in code that reports a PEP8 violation, either the formatter is wrong or the implementation of the standard is wrong. I think it is the latter.

If you use a tuple or list for the type hint there is no issue, but I feel a set is the most appropriate data structure, a tuple could imply that 'a' is a tuple of one string and one None e.g. ("hello", None).

```
def foo(a: (str, None) = None):
    print("This is the result after formatting, no PEP8 violation is reported")
```